# ¿Por qué cuando cambio de branch en git, mi proyecto no compila?

Tags: android-studio, git, ide, clone

> Buen día comunidad, he batallado bastante con un proyecto que después de clonarlo y cambiarme a otra rama, no compila, se queda en **"Gradle project sync in progress.."**
>
> Dentro de la opción Run / Debug configurations me da este error:

**Error: Gradle project sync failed. Please fix your project and try again.**

> Les dejo algunos datos de referencia y los pasos que he seguido para tratar de resolverlo

- **Android Studio Artic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 3**
- **Clean project**
- **Rebuild project**
- **Make project**
- **Sync project with gradle files**
- **Invalidate caches / restart**

Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias

Comment: ¿Checaste esta pregunta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29275413/android-studio-alway-show-gradle-project-sync-in-progress ?

Comment: Si obtienes este error "Error: Gradle project sync failed. Please fix your project and try again." seguramente se muestran mensajes del error en la parte inferior de Android Studio , agregalos a tu pregunta.